# Same menu opened in two different JFrames works only on the last one

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I'm trying to write a simple Paint application in which the user will be able to open new `JFrames` (in new Threads) with Drawing Panels, and each of those frames will have a `JMenuBar` on top, however, only the last open frame has a functional menu bar, all the remaining (open) frames show menu but the menu doesn't work (nothing happens when I click). Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've simplified the code to leave only the sections regarding `JMenuBar`.

The code consists of the following classes:

Main.java

```
package sample;

public class Main {

    Main() {

        MainFrameThread.getMainFrameThread().run();

    }//end of Main()

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}//end of Main class
```

TopMenu.java

```
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TopMenu extends JMenuBar {

    private JMenu menu_File;
    private static JMenuItem menu_New;

    public static JMenuItem getMenu_New() {
        return menu_New;
    }

    public TopMenu() {

        menu_File = new JMenu("File");
        menu_New = new JMenuItem("New");
        this.add(menu_File);
        menu_File.add(menu_New);

    }//end of TopMenu()

}//end of TopMenu extends JMenuBar
```

MainFrameThread.java

```
package sample;

public class MainFrameThread extends Thread {

    private static MainFrameThread mainFrameThread = new MainFrameThread();

    public static MainFrameThread getMainFrameThread() {
        return mainFrameThread;
    }

    public MainFrameThread() {}

    @Override
    public void run() {

        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();

    }//end of public void run()

}//end of public class FrameSizeDialogThread
```

ActionController.java

```
package sample;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ActionController {

    private static ActionController actionController = new ActionController();
    private ListenForMenu listenForMenu = new ListenForMenu();

    public static ActionController getActionController() {
        return actionController;
    }

    public ActionController() {}

    public void clickOnMenu(TopMenu topMenu) {
        TopMenu.getMenu_New().addActionListener(listenForMenu);
    }

    //listener for menu
    public class ListenForMenu implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

            if(ev.getSource() == TopMenu.getMenu_New()) {
                MainFrame newMainFrame = new MainFrame();
            }//end of if(ev.getSource() == TopMenu.getMenu_New())

        }//end of public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
    }//end of public class ListenForMenu

}//end of ActionController class
```

and MainFrame.java

```
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint Application");

        //creating menu
        TopMenu topMenu = new TopMenu();
        ActionController.getActionController().clickOnMenu(topMenu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(topMenu);

        //frame properties
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }//end of public MainFrame()

}//end of public class MainFrame
```

I'm stuck, nothing works, regardless where I initialise the MainFrame.java. Does anyone see the mistake???

Comment: One component can only appear once. *"the user will be able to open new `JFrame` windows (in new Threads)"* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) All Swing components should be created and updated on the (single) Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: What Andrew said. You will run into concurrency problems. Moreover, your particular problem may have something to do with which frame has focus.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for sharing that post with me, it gave me many ideas as how to redesign my application and have future other options. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however, only the last open frame has a functional menu bar

Swing components can't be shared. A Swing component can only have a single parent. So for every child window you will need to create a new `JMenuBar` and `JMenu` and `JMenuItem`.

However, the `Action` used by the `JMenuItem` can be shared.

```
private static JMenuItem menu_New;

public static JMenuItem getMenu_New() {
    return menu_New;
}
```

None of the variable or methods related to the menus should be static. Again, you need to create a unique instance of each.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I'm still relatively new to Java so each comment like this makes it easier for me to learn! Thank you!